# Pull-down faucet hose doesn't slide into sink/counter holes

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet, sink

Little bit of a *thing* here (and also my first time trying anything remotely like a plumbing project):

I'm trying to replace a leaky pull-down kitchen faucet hose. I saw it was suggested to take the existing hose to the store to compare with, but I didn't have any luck finding the right hose at my local stores. So I wanted to replace my current hose for now so I'd have *something* in the meantime until I can get a new one from the manufacturer. But when I try to slide the hose back through the faucet and down through the holes, it seems like it just won't fit and gets stuck. It did take a little extra effort to remove the hose from the faucet in the first place, but not tons.

Additionally, I tried to hook the hose up directly under the sink without going through the faucet. Again, so I could have some semblance of a kitchen sink for now. But when I turn the water on, it flows out of the hole that the hose would go through, instead of the supply hose. I'm assuming this is unexpected even though that hole would normally have the pull-down hose going through it. Is it possible that the supply hose is dislodged in the faucet, causing both problems? I'm worried that even if I do get a new hose, I might need to disassemble the faucet in order to fix whatever is going on in there.

Thanks for any help.

Photos:

[image: Supply hoses]
[image: Faucet]
[image: Pull-down hose connector]
[image: Pull-down hose]
[image: Supply lines]

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen. [Edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/217737/edit) your question to add a few so we can see what you're talking about - there are many, many different kinds of pull-down sink faucets, each with their own particular connection styles.

Comment: I fear that you have pulled apart things you should not have, and may be looking a new faucet in the face, but it's hard to tell for sure from this side of the screen. You might [edit] to add some pictures, but "taking the hose to the store" is more of a "side sprayer option" than a pull-down faucet option, where you normally remove the faucet and hose together, and pulling the hose all the way out of the faucet might have been a *bad* idea.

Comment: That's a little scary. I appreciate the quick and helpful responses even without the photos. I've gone ahead and added some. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I agree with @brhans 100%. The connection method (and threads, on those that are threaded; not all are) are proprietary, i.e. *not standardized in any way*. You cannot go to a plumbing store and grab a generic pull-down faucet sprayer hose off of the shelf. Every manufacturer makes them differently. You will absolutely need to wait for the exact replacement hose for **your** faucet if you hope to ever make it work again.

Comment: It's hard to say because the pic is so blurry, but the threads at the end of the hose appear to be a bit mangled. If that's the case, that could have been the source of your original leak, and, even with a factory fresh replacement hose, could continue to cause leaks if the threads that it attaches to are mangled, too. You _might_ be able to chase the threads with an appropriate tap, but if it's as bespoke as @JimmyFix-it suggests, you may not find a tap to fit. That means a whole new faucet, not just a new hose.

Comment: Sorry about the blurry picture, but yeah. The threads were slightly mangled before I got down there. I think the connection may have been over-tightened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, it is often cheaper to just buy a new faucet....if you decide to go the repair route, try to identify the brand and model of your faucet by going to the manufacturer's web site.

This is why I always advise to keep the faucet box for future reference on make and model. Parts are then much easier to identify with parts explosion diagrams from the manufacturer. Good luck!

Comment: The OP should consider his time as well. While it may or may not be cheaper to replace the faucet, it'll often be quicker and easier to replace rather than repair.